# Can not use same variable name in different go file

Tags: go, go-packages

Here is my first go file：

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

var db13 *sql.DB
```

then, I create the second go file:

```
package main

import "database/sql"

var db13 *sql.DB
```

I got an error saying that: ''db13' redeclared in this package'

Am I miss anything here?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is another file, both are package main.

Comment: The hint is in the error message: "redeclared in this **package**", not "redeclared in this *file*".

Answer (score 0):

both file are in "package main"  so if you think about it like they are in the namespace

Comment: if I change the main to "dd" for example, I get "Multiple packages in the directory: dd, main". so, in go,  I can not use different packages name under the same directory

Comment: yes, dir is a package in go. you can simply rename one of the 2  variables  or create 2  packages

Answer (score 0):

They are in same package thus it is not allowed. Also different packages in same directory are not allowed.

`db13` declared in `first.go` can be accessed and used in `second.go`. No need to declare it again.